# How to get this rainbow air type effect

Tags: materials

How can i get below image type of rainbow color with spikes and spherical effect. Is it possible and how.

[image]

I have created a smoke effect and added this color nodes to it.

[image]

**This was my result**

[image]

Any suggestion or help.

Comment: This looks like some peacock feathers like image with mixed lensflare in it. If you want a volumetric 3D effect, it is extremely hard to do in Blender. You would have to come up with math that generates that shader. If you want a 2D type effect (billboard particles etc.) photoshop or similar app is the tool to use to make the texture.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny Yes you got it correct. Its the lens flare. But no problem with the flare we can add it . Rest of the shade